# EfCore and calling "service stored procedures"

Tags: stored-procedures, ef-core-3.1

Is the calling of an SP in Ef Core always bound to the return of an entity?

I want to call a Sp that make only "dirty job" (eg. a series of TRUNCATE)

Should I return at the end a "fake" select * from **MyEntity** only to call
context.**MyEntity**.FromSqlRaw(sql);

Thanks

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You could execute raw sql on the database context.

```
await _context.Database.ExecuteSqlRawAsync("EXEC dbo.YourStoredProcedure");
```

Read more:

https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/dotnet/api/microsoft.entityframeworkcore.relationaldatabasefacadeextensions.executesqlrawasync?view=efcore-3.1

Comment: Perfect!. Thanks sir.